# How to create a stored procedure that will search for a record in a table with given param by client app and return the found row data?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, netbeans

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will be used by a client application to search for customers in a `customers` table and then return all the info about the customer if he's found. I've created a procedure to add a customer to the table:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE `add_cust` (IN custF VARCHAR(100), IN custL VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customers (cFirst, cLast) VALUES(custF, custL);
END $
```

And it works.

My `customers` table is very simple - an auto-incrementing primary key, fist and last name columns.

I can't wrap my head around this other `search` procedure. The way I see it is to have two procedures for searching. One procedure uses `First Name` to search for customer, and the second one will use `Last Name`.

I assume I'll have to use a cursor `FOR SELECT` with `WHERE` clause, and a `WHILE` loop. But how do I return the result to the client application? Do I declare one of the parameters in the stored procedure as `OUT`? Or do I just declare one parameter as `INOUT`?

So far this is where I am at:

```
DELIMETER $

CREATE PROCEDURE `searchCustByFirst` (IN custF VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

END $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simply -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchCustByFirst(IN custF VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  SELECT cFirst, cLast FROM customers WHERE cFirst = custF;
END
```

This procedure will return dataset, just read it in the application.

Another solution is to use OUT parameters, for example -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchCustByFirst(IN custF VARCHAR(100), OUT custL VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  SELECT cLast INTO custL FROM customers WHERE cFirst = custF;
END
```

In this case SELECT statement cannot return more then one record, so criteria field `cFirst` should be unique.

Comment: The first solution will require a multi statement connection to return a result set from a stored procedure.  Just so the asker knows to set that option...